# Execute worker thread and show state on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I try to create an wpf application that show the running process state on textbox. This running process will run on worker thread, and everytime the process state changed, it should change textbox text too.

The class, that responsible for changing state looks

```
   public class OutputText
    {
        public event ProcessEventArgsHandler processEventArgsHandler;

        private void OnProcessHandler(String text)
        {
            if (processEventArgsHandler != null)
            {
                processEventArgsHandler(this, new ProcessEventArgs(text));
            }
        }

        public void SimulateProcessOutput()
        {
            OnProcessHandler("Process Started.");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OnProcessHandler("Process 1");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OnProcessHandler("Process 2");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OnProcessHandler("Process 3");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OnProcessHandler("Process 4");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            OnProcessHandler("Process Ended.");
        }
    }
```

Look at method SimulateProcessOutput(), it will call later the event handler to change text.

Event

```
public class ProcessEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private readonly String _state;

    public String State
    {
        get { return _state; }
    }

    public ProcessEventArgs(String state)
    {
        _state = state;
    }
}
```

and delegate

```
public delegate void ProcessEventArgsHandler(object s, ProcessEventArgs e);
```

Finally, wpf code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static Task _task;
    private static TaskScheduler _taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    private static CancellationToken _cancelToken = new CancellationToken();

    public static Task ProTask {
        get { return _task; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ProcessEventHandler(object s, ProcessEventArgs e)
    {
        _processText.Text = e.State;
    }

    private void StartProcess()
    {
        var outputText = new OutputText();
        outputText.processEventArgsHandler += ProcessEventHandler;
        outputText.SimulateProcessOutput();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(StartProcess, _cancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, _taskScheduler);
    }
}
```

When i run the application, only the last text is shown, the other don't appear.

> Process Ended

How can i programming the application in the way, that the textbox shows text one after the other, like

> Process Started.
>
> Wait 200ms
>
> Process 1.
>
> ........

Comment: Don't you think 200ms is probably too quick for you to be able to observe other texts?

Comment: 200ms should be fine, however did you try with higher values?

Comment: yes. I try with 2000ms the result is the same. The problem is because of threading.

Comment: I tested and saw that indeed. Edited my answer, and gonna try to get you some working code.

Comment: Either use `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke()` with `DispatcherPriority.Input` or use a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, Dispatcher.Invoke, here the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static Task _task;
    private static TaskScheduler _taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    private static CancellationToken _cancelToken = new CancellationToken();

    public static Task ProTask {
        get { return _task; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ProcessEventHandler(object s, ProcessEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                (Action)(() => { _processText.Text = e.State; }));
    }

    private void StartProcess()
    {
        var outputText = new OutputText();
        outputText.processEventArgsHandler += ProcessEventHandler;
        outputText.SimulateProcessOutput();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(StartProcess);
    }
}
```

Look add ProcessEventHandler, with Dispatcher, it is possible to control UI thread. Read the article [Dispatcher](http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf)

Comment: Eh, that will be easier that what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I think you didn't need to show all this code, the problem lies here

```
    _processText.Text = e.State;
```

Replace it with

```
    _processText.AppendText(e.State);
    _processText.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
```

Because obviously, `= e.State` will replace the content, showing indeed only the last text passed.

EDIT

Ok, that was not the problem. The problem is that Task here is actually UI thread-blocking. You may want to rewrite your code using [Task.ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can easily find [examples](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/11/17/synchronizing-net-4-tasks-with-the-ui-thread/) on the net.

Or if you're using C# 4.5/5, you can also do some [neat thing with async/await](http://www.csharp-examples.net/asynchronous-method-progress/).

Comment: i will change the text not append it. The text should change delay time

Comment: Oh I see, ok. It would have been a bit too easy uh :p